# Beginning youtube API fetch?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube

I'm a little confused for the terminology surrounding what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically, I want to generate an eleven character key, attach it to the "watch?v=" of the youtube url and check if the video exists, if it's view-able, and then open the video in the web browser. Just a little side thing I'm wanting to create to find random videos I wouldn't otherwise see.

```
ID=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "_" + "-")for_in range(11))
```

`webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + ID)`

this is what I've reduced my code to simply to make sure the ID is generating the correct amount of characters, but I've tried urllib2 among other things, here is an example of an early, although messy, trial code

```
API = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "_" + "-") for _ in range(11))


API_TEST = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEOID&part=status&key=" + r0iSQLDBkKQ

ret = urllib.urlopen(API_TEST)

website2 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + API

while ret.code != 200:
    print '404'
    API = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "_" + "-") for _ in range(11))
    API_TEST = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEOID&part=status&key=" + API

    ret = urllib.urlopen(API_TEST)
else:
    print '200'
```

I've been trying to find an answer for a hour and a half now, and I'd really appreciate this being explained and figuring it all out (sorry for the mess of code, I tried to correct it but it wouldn't fix)

Comment: Considering the number of possible keys and the estimated number of videos on Youtube, your chances for a hit should be far worse than one in a million. So, good luck!

Comment: what is the problem and the question here?

Comment: I'm having trouble fetching a valid video, it can generate the 11 character key for the video, but it has yet to pull up an actual, view-able video. I want to be able to make sure that the video is a valid, view-able video and **then** open it in my browser